# Bootstrap element not stacking correctly in Firefox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

On an online store category page I've built, I use the Twitter Bootstrap grid system to form a product catalogue page. The page can be viewed here: http://sergedenimes.com/shop/?view=all

Essentially, in normal desktop browser width the class `col-md-4` means each product `div` takes up 1/3 of the column width, which allows 3 to stack on each row. All the product `divs` are on one row so as to allow the `col-sm-6` class to cause 2 on each row on smaller screens.

On Chrome the result looks like this which is intended:

[image]

However, on Firefox it seems on or two of the divs is skipping the first two divs and positioning itself beneath the 3rd leaving blank space on its left and only 1 product on this row. Like so:

[image]

Having examined the source and computed css all divs are the same height and width and I can't seem to find out why it's behaving like this, especially as it's just normal Bootstrap markup. Can anyone explain why Firefox is rendering the page like this and how I could solve it?

**EDIT**

Here is the code in question. Apologies for the extensive classes and attributes

```
<div class="post-22064 product type-product status-publish has-post-thumbnail col-md-4 col-xs-6 top-buffer pif-has-gallery taxable shipping-taxable purchasable product-type-variable product-cat-bomber-jackets instock"> <a href="http://sergedenimes.com/shop/bomber-jackets/wolf-bomber-jacket/">

        <img width="240" height="330" src="http://sergedenimes.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/SDN-18-1-240x330.jpg" class="attachment-shop_catalog wp-post-image" alt="SDN-18 (1)">
            <img width="240" height="330" src="http://sergedenimes.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/IMG_1042-240x330.jpg" class="secondary-image attachment-shop-catalog" alt="IMG_1042" />       
            <div class="catalog-info">
        <h3>Wolf Bomber Jacket</h3>
    <span class="price"><span class="amount">&pound;125.00</span></span>
        </div>
    </a>

</div>
<div class="post-20523 product type-product status-publish has-post-thumbnail col-md-4 col-xs-6 top-buffer last pif-has-gallery taxable shipping-taxable purchasable product-type-variable product-cat-so-serge product-cat-sweatpants instock"> <a href="http://sergedenimes.com/shop/so-serge/so-serge-sweatpants/">

        <img width="193" height="265" src="http://sergedenimes.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/SDN21-38-193x265.jpg" class="attachment-shop_catalog wp-post-image" alt="SDN21-38">
            <img width="193" height="265" src="http://sergedenimes.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/IMG_8080-193x265.jpg" class="secondary-image attachment-shop-catalog" alt="IMG_8080" />       
            <div class="catalog-info">
        <h3>So Serge Sweatpants</h3>

    <span class="price"><span class="amount">&pound;60.00</span></span>
        </div>
    </a>

</div>
<div class="post-20904 product type-product status-publish has-post-thumbnail col-md-4 col-xs-6 top-buffer first pif-has-gallery taxable shipping-taxable purchasable product-type-variable product-cat-sweatpants instock">    <a href="http://sergedenimes.com/shop/sweatpants/sdn-camo-sweatpants-pre-order/">

        <img width="240" height="330" src="http://sergedenimes.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/SDN-29-1-e1415103678561-240x330.jpg" class="attachment-shop_catalog wp-post-image" alt="SDN-29 (1)">
            <img width="240" height="330" src="http://sergedenimes.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/IMG_8995-copy-240x330.jpg" class="secondary-image attachment-shop-catalog" alt="IMG_8995 copy" />
            <div class="catalog-info">
        <h3>SDN Camo Sweatpants</h3>


    <span class="price"><span class="amount">&pound;65.00</span></span>
        </div>
    </a>

</div>
<div class="post-17753 product type-product status-publish has-post-thumbnail col-md-4 col-xs-6 top-buffer pif-has-gallery taxable shipping-taxable purchasable product-type-variable product-cat-harvey-nichols-exclusive-2 product-cat-t-shirts instock"> <a href="http://sergedenimes.com/shop/harvey-nichols-exclusive-2/vertical-symbol-print-t-shirt/">

        <img width="193" height="265" src="http://sergedenimes.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/501309_black_1-193x265.jpg" class="attachment-shop_catalog wp-post-image" alt="501309_black_1">
            <img width="193" height="265" src="http://sergedenimes.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/MG_8210-Edit-copy-193x265.jpg" class="secondary-image attachment-shop-catalog" alt="_MG_8210-Edit-copy" />    
            <div class="catalog-info">
        <h3>Vertical Symbol Print T-Shirt</h3>
    <span class="price"><span class="amount">&pound;55.00</span></span>
        </div>
    </a>

</div>
<div class="post-17786 product type-product status-publish has-post-thumbnail col-md-4 col-xs-6 top-buffer last pif-has-gallery taxable shipping-taxable purchasable product-type-variable product-cat-harvey-nichols-exclusive-2 product-cat-t-shirts instock"> <a href="http://sergedenimes.com/shop/harvey-nichols-exclusive-2/panel-symbol-print-t-shirt/">

        <img width="193" height="265" src="http://sergedenimes.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/500774_black_1-193x265.jpg" class="attachment-shop_catalog wp-post-image" alt="500774_black_1">
            <img width="193" height="265" src="http://sergedenimes.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/MG_8215-Edit-copy-193x265.jpg" class="secondary-image attachment-shop-catalog" alt="_MG_8215-Edit-copy" />
            <div class="catalog-info">
        <h3>Panel Symbol Print T-Shirt</h3>
    <span class="price"><span class="amount">&pound;55.00</span></span>
        </div>
    </a>

</div>
```

I'm aware that some images are different sizes but I was under the impression that the css rule `width:100%; height:auto;` applied to the images should override the width/height attributes in the image tags themselves.

Comment: Well the images are not the same size. Chrome may be more forgiving, but Firefox is not. All the images, except the one not lining up, are 193 x 265 but this one is 240 x 330. This is normal float behavior.

Comment: Wouldn't the css rule `width:100%; height:auto` override the size attributes in the image tag?

Comment: Please include the relevant code with your solution. Can't easily access the code on a live site, and going forward the code for that site may change, which will make the relevancy of this question and any answers it recieves pointless.

Comment: This is common float behavior. Chrome is being forgiving. Size those images to equal heights

Comment: fixed once the images were resized. Weird though as they all display the same size but Firefox treats them differently for layout

Answer (score 0):

I think for all the columns to line up properly in bootstrap, each line of columns need to be in their own row and I think in your page, all the columns are in one row.

Comment: I shouldn't think so - the whole point in the `col-md-`, `col-sm-` etc classes is to allow a responsive grid system where elements take up different widths of the container depending on window size. If there were 3 a `.row` div for each 3 product divs then the 2-per-row small-screen view wouldn't work

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue on a project that I was working on, my recommendation is to use `<div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>` you can change the md for lg or something else depending on what you are trying to do, in my case I generated my product list with php, I have it so that on a large screen I have col-lg-3 and on medium col-md-4, sometimes since the images or text description where of diferent sizes i would have the blank space, I fixed this by adding a counter variable and using modulus to add the clearfix.

```
foreach($deal as $element){

                if ($x % 4 ==0) { echo '<div class="clearfix visible-lg-block"></div>';};
                if ($x % 3 ==0) { echo '<div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>';};
                    echo '<div class = "col-md-4 col-lg-3">'.print_regular_item($element).'</div>';

                $x++;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

this is height issue define the height of your `col-*-*` make the `custom class` define height of `gird col` if you don't want to define `height` of `col-*-*` don't wanna create any `custom class` so simple i have other suggestion for you equal `col-*-*` height.

use this `row-eq-height` class for your with `row`

```
/*
 * Row with equal height columns
 * --------------------------------------------------
 */
.row-eq-height {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display:         flex;
}
```

source: http://getbootstrap.com.vn/examples/equal-height-columns/